# Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method: Variant.getDesugaredMethods(). The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea

Woke up to this issue, not sure where to go from here.
Even running gradle with --stacktrace or --scan, I can't seem to understand what exactly it wants me to do. How can I fix this? Thank you.

```
Unsupported method: Variant.getDesugaredMethods().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
```

[image]

Comment: Try to set the gradle version in your IDE.
Go under Settings -> Build -> Build Tools -> Gradle and change the "Build and Run using" to Gradle. Set "Use Gradle from" to the gradle-wrapper.properties file and select toe correct Gradle JVM version

Comment: Cant seem to find "build and run using". I updated question with screenshot.

Comment: I reported it to their issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232107692

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had this issue after using gradle wrapper 7.3.3 & com.android.library version 7.2 on Dolphin.

Dropping to Chipmunk worked.

Answer (score 2):

Update your android gradle plugin to the `7.3.0-alpha09` version and
gradle wrapper to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip`

Comment: I now get this error. I am suspecting it doesn't have anything to do with gradle version.

Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.AndroidLintWorkAction
   > Internal error: Unexpected lint invalid arguments

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is a bug in Dolphin, that should hopefully be fixed soon - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227524922?pli=1

Until then, rolling back to Chipmunk as @Bob Saget suggests may be the best option

Edit: This seems to be fixed in Electric Eel